# Mysql. Select where field=1 or field=2 with IF

Tags: mysql, sorting, if-statement

i need some query.

```
CREATE TABLE `location_areas_localized` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang_index` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `lang_index` (`lang_index`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_2` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `location_areas_localized` (`id`, `lang_index`,`name`)
VALUES
    (1,'ru','Нью Йорк'),
    (1,'en','New York'),
    (2,'en','Boston'),
    (2,'ch','波士顿')
;
```

Logic of search.

If row with `lang_index='ru' AND id IN(1,2)` found. it must return all with `lang_index='ru'`
If one or more rows with `lang_index='ru'` not exists But exists with `lang_index='en'` and with some id.
Then it must return all exists with `land_index='ru' AND id IN(1,2)` and all that not found with `lang_index='ru'` but found with `lang_index='en'` (in table - all rows with `lang_index='en'` always exists)

See on [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87caa/1/0)

I need only one result per id. I tried GROUP BY id but its not works correctly.

Output must be

```
  1,'ru','Нью Йорк'

   2,'en','Boston'   (because lang_index='ru' with id 2  not found)
```

Comment: your question is too confusing, what will be the output of the sample records above?

Comment: I need one result per id (id IN (1,2)) with lang_index='ru' if than not exitsts than return with lang_index='en'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(max(CASE WHEN lang_index='ru' THEN name ELSE null END), name) as name
FROM 
  location_areas_localized 
WHERE 
  id IN (1,2) 
  AND (lang_index='en' OR lang_index='ru')
group by 
  id
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(lang_index,'ru','en');
```

Comment: Yes i think that simple. SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM location_areas_localized
    ORDER BY FIELD(lang_index,'ru','en','ch')
) as inv
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id

Comment: It may seem simpler. It's wildly inefficient.

Comment: Or i have mistake with chooses?

Comment: Ok. i see evidence. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Without using aggregation functions, it only takes the first matching row. The subquery with `ORDER BY` enforce the fact that for the same `id` either the "ru" (or "en", if "ru" is not present) row is the first one.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM location_areas_localized
    ORDER BY FIELD(lang_index,'ru','en','ch')
) as inv
WHERE id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df2f/5) example

Comment: this query will not work, see here. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6df2f/1 please fix this so you'll not get any downvotes `:D`

Comment: That would be highly inefficient as you are scanning the entire table, loading all rows, and then running a second query on that!

Comment: I agree, but I thought it would be simpler to understand.